# How to use the search.asmx service to search a particular library?

Tags: search, enterprise-search

Let's say I have a library, `mylibrary`, that I want to search in using the search web service. How would I do that? So far I have tried this MSSQLFT query:

```
SELECT Title, Description, Path, Rank
FROM SCOPE()
WHERE FREETEXT(defaultproperties, 'test')
  AND "PATH" LIKE '%mylibrary%'
  AND "SCOPE" = 'All Sites'
ORDER BY Rank DESC
```

If I run this query, I get no results. If I remove the `PATH` condition I get a result with a path like:

```
http://sharepoint/mylibrary/test.docx
```

This makes no sense to me. Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is it just not supposed to work this way? How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using SharePoint 2010 then you shouldn't use the [SQL syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558869.aspx) the [keyword syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558911.aspx) is simple just use

> site:mylibrary test

Comment: So you're saying I should just use `<QueryText type="STRING">`? That doesn't seem to work, I don't get any results. I have tried both on the SharePoint site and through the API.

Comment: First test your query string on the search page. Then just user type="STRING"

Comment: Well, I tried your suggestion, `site:mylibrary test`, and I got not results.

Comment: Are you using just mylibrary or the full URL to mylibrary? It should be the latter, so in your case the query should be "site:http://sharepoint/mylibrary test"

Comment: thank you all for help and direction